# What is the Difference between exclusive & inclusive quartile calculation in power BI?

Tags: powerbi

In power BI there is two options to calculate quartile. Exclusive & Inclusive. I'm unable to understand the difference between two. Can you please help me understand using one example?

Answer (score 1):

Check info from https://dax.guide/percentile-exc/:

> PERCENTILE.EXC computed the k-th percentile, exclusive
> PERCENTILE.INC computed the k-th percentile, inclusive
>
> Both functions rank the N values from 1 (lowest)  to N (highest),
> then determine the possibly-non-integer   calculated rank for the
> specified percentage argument K   (a decimal number between 0.00 and
> 1.00), and finally   use linear interpolation between the closest integer-rank   values of the data array.
>
> For PERCENTILE.EXC the calculated rank is K*(N+1)  For PERCENTILE.INC
> the calculated rank is K*(N-1)+1
>
> MEDIAN corresponds to PERCENTILE.INC with k=0.50

```
DEFINE
    TABLE SampleData = { 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9 }
EVALUATE
{
     ( "AVERAGE",  AVERAGE ( SampleData[Value] ) ),
     ( "MEDIAN",   MEDIAN ( SampleData[Value] ) ),
     ( "PERCENTILE.EXC 0.25",  PERCENTILE.EXC ( SampleData[Value], 0.25 ) ),
     ( "PERCENTILE.INC 0.25",  PERCENTILE.INC ( SampleData[Value], 0.25 ) ),
     ( "PERCENTILE.EXC 0.50",  PERCENTILE.EXC ( SampleData[Value], 0.50 ) ),
     ( "PERCENTILE.INC 0.50",  PERCENTILE.INC ( SampleData[Value], 0.50 ) ),
     ( "PERCENTILE.EXC 0.75",  PERCENTILE.EXC ( SampleData[Value], 0.75 ) ),
     ( "PERCENTILE.INC 0.75",  PERCENTILE.INC ( SampleData[Value], 0.75 ) )
}
```

[image]